# Make it linkable

Tags: php, html, css

Okay I donwload a css / html template my code is below and I have tried everything how can I restrucuture this so it will allow me to add a link

```
<a class="dashboard-module">
    <img src="Crystal_Clear_write.gif"
         tppabs="http://www.xooom.pl/work/magicadmin/images/Crystal_Clear_write.gif"
         width="64" height="64" alt="edit" />
    <span>Upload Ad</span>
</a>
```

And obviously im adding a link like this but its not working cause of the ending I believe

```
<a class="dashboard-module">
    <img src="Crystal_Clear_write.gif"
         tppabs="http://www.xooom.pl/work/magicadmin/images/Crystal_Clear_write.gif"
         width="64" height="64" alt="edit" />
    <span><a href="UploadContent.html">Upload Ad</span>
</a>
```

Comment: You cannot nest `<a>` tags. You will need to explain where you want to place this new link

Comment: well you are not adding link properly ... in second you just started tow link and closed one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an `href` attribute to your anchor:

```
<a class="dashboard-module" href="http://www.mylink.com">
    <img src="Crystal_Clear_write.gif"
         tppabs="http://www.xooom.pl/work/magicadmin/images/Crystal_Clear_write.gif"
         width="64" height="64" alt="edit" />
    <span>Upload Ad</span>
</a>
```

Comment: I have a feeling there's some JS or something that uses the original `<a>` tag. There may be a `click` event listener that could void any `href` attribute. Why else would that `<a>` be there?

Comment: That's way too logical Phil :) I think this is just a simple snipped copy/paste lack of HTML understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<a class="dashboard-module" href="UploadContent.html">
    <img src="http://www.xooom.pl/work/magicadmin/images/Crystal_Clear_write.gif"
     tppabs="http://www.xooom.pl/work/magicadmin/images/Crystal_Clear_write.gif"
     width="64" height="64" alt="edit" />
    <span>Upload Ad</span>
</a>
```

Comment: Why the downvote? This looks correct, although poorly documented.